# Invalid controller specified (scripts) in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am totally newbie in Zend and I am trying to run [this script](http://github.com/giovanniramos/zf_generate_models) in the Zend Framework.
I have done all steps included in github but unfortunately I receive an error

```
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (scripts)

Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /var/www/html/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/html/zend/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /var/www/html/zend/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  
Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'scripts',
  'action' => 'zf1_generator',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With that just information, I think it would be difficult to answer your question. So you tried to access it by <host name>/scripts/zf1_generator? right? You have an existing working project and you just added it right?